# DOMDocument hangs on missing image

Tags: php, image, html-parsing, domdocument

I'm using DOMDocument to replace img src/height/width to format dynamically depending on the containing div size.  It works fine except if it tries to parse an image that has been deleted from the server, which generally won't happen, but isn't impossible so we need to handle it if so.

Any ideas how I would do that?

Thanks!

```
    $dom=new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($footer, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
    $imgs = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
    foreach($imgs as $img) {            

        // Resize 
        $src = $img->getAttribute('src');
        $params = array( 'width' => $width );
        $new_src = bfi_thumb( $src, $params );
        $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $new_src );

        // Set new dimensions
        $size = getimagesize($new_src);
        $img->removeAttribute('height');
        $img->removeAttribute('width');
        $img->setAttribute('height', $size[1]);
        $img->setAttribute('width', $size[0]);
    }   
    $footer = $dom->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if the image exists before performing any action:

```
$src = $img->getAttribute('src');
$exists = file_get_contents($src, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
if($exists) {
    $params = array( 'width' => $width );
    $new_src = bfi_thumb( $src, $params );
    $img->setAttribute( 'src' , $new_src );

    // Set new dimensions
    $size = getimagesize($new_src);
    $img->removeAttribute('height');
    $img->removeAttribute('width');
    $img->setAttribute('height', $size[1]);
    $img->setAttribute('width', $size[0]);
}
```

If this needs to be used often, it may be better as a function.

```
function srcExists($src) {
    $exists = file_get_contents($src, NULL, NULL, NULL, 1);
    return ($exists) ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: But doesn't `src` contain a URL, not a file path? This would only work if `src` just had something like "image.png" and that was in the current working directory.

Comment: A url is a file path.

Comment: I added to the script in case it has trouble accessing it via the url, you can use file_get_contents() instead.

Comment: I added parameters to file_get_contents(), so check it again. The 1 is to stop it from downloading more than 1 byte of the file, rather than the entire file, since you only need to see if any of it is there.

Comment: Thank you very much, that worked a treat.  Learned something new about file_get_contents with the 1 byte thing ;)